# About sql server2008 running total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table , the table structure is:

```
TransactionRecordID  State   TransactionMoney  CreateTime
      1                1          200            2014/6/19

      2                0          100            2014/6/12

      3                1          50             2014/3/17

      4                1          400            2014/2/23

      ......
```

I want to get the result:

```
TransactionRecordID   State    TransactionMoney  CreateTime  TotalMoney
          1            1          200            2014/6/19      650

          2            0          100            2014/6/12      450

          3            1          50             2014/3/17      450

          4            1          400            2014/2/23      400
```

If current record field `state=1`,I would like to get sum TransactionMoney after current

record add current TransactionMoney , else get sum TransactionMoney after current record

Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 makes this a lot simpler using `SUM() OVER (ORDER BY ...)`, but in SQL Server 2008 you can use a LEFT JOIN for the same effect;

```
SELECT a.TransactionRecordID, a.State, a.TransactionMoney, a.CreateTime,
       COALESCE(SUM(b.TransactionMoney), 0) TotalMoney
FROM transactions a
LEFT JOIN transactions b ON a.CreateTime >= b.CreateTime AND b.state = 1
GROUP BY a.TransactionRecordID, a.State, a.TransactionMoney, a.CreateTime
ORDER BY a.TransactionRecordID;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31288/2).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CTE Example for Northwind.  it might give you some alternate ideas.

```
Use Northwind 

GO

declare @CustomerID varchar(6)

declare @BeginDate datetime

declare @EndDate datetime

select @CustomerID = (select top 1 CustomerID from dbo.Orders )

select @BeginDate = '01/01/1900'

select @EndDate = '12/31/2010'

;
WITH
MyCTE /* http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx */
( ShipName,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry,CustomerID,CustomerName,[Address],
City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Salesperson,OrderID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipperName,
ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount,ExtendedPrice,Freight,ROWID) AS
(
SELECT
ShipName ,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry,CustomerID,CustomerName,[Address]
,City ,Region,PostalCode,Country,Salesperson,OrderID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipperName
,ProductID ,ProductName,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount,ExtendedPrice,Freight
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderDate , ProductName ASC ) as ROWID
FROM
dbo.Invoices inv /* “Invoices” is a VIEW, FYI */
where
inv.CustomerID = @CustomerID and (inv.OrderDate between @BeginDate and @EndDate)
)
SELECT
/*
ShipName,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry,CustomerID,CustomerName,[Address],
City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Salesperson,OrderID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipperName,
ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount,ExtendedPrice,Freight,
*/

/*trim the list down a little for the final output */

CustomerID ,Salesperson,OrderID,OrderDate,ProductName,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount,ExtendedPrice,Freight,(ExtendedPrice + Freight) as ComputedTotal

/*The below line is the “trick”. I reference the above CTE, but only get data that is less than or equal to the row that I am on (outerAlias.ROWID)*/
, (Select SUM (ExtendedPrice + Freight) from MyCTE innerAlias where innerAlias.ROWID <= outerAlias.ROWID ) as RunningTotal
, ROWID as ROWID_SHOWN_FOR_KICKS , OrderDate as OrderDateASecondTimeForConvenience
FROM
MyCTE outerAlias

/*Two Order By Options*/
ORDER BY outerAlias.OrderDate , ProductName

/* << Whatever the ORDER BY is here, should match the “ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ________ ASC )” statement inside the CTE */
/*ORDER BY outerAlias.ROWID */ /* << Or, to keep is more “trim”, ORDER BY the ROWID, which will of course be the same as the “ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY” inside the CTE */
```